# How to disable edit first line of RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I set first line of richtextbox by

```
RichTextBox.text = "Comment:";
```

I want this line read only, and input from second line, and get text begin from second line.

Any suggustion? Thanks!

---

Thanks, I add a `MouseClick` event to forbid first line editable:

```
 private void CommentTxtBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = _commentTxtBox.SelectionStart;
        int line = _commentTxtBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(index);
        if (line == 0)
        {
            _commentTxtBox.ReadOnly = true;
        }
        else
            _commentTxtBox.ReadOnly = false;

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a label `Comment:` then a rich textbox completely editable?

Comment: @Rafalon Is it hard to implement?

Comment: Well a label then a completely editable control is what 99% of forms are made of so I don't think it is *hard to implement*. You very likely can find tons of examples on the internet

Comment: The Label will not be selected or copied. When nested It will overlay the RTB's text; when not nested it will not be integrated. When saving you will need to append it to the text, including formatting. It will not be printed. - So, there are some drawbacks, which may or may not matter to you..

Comment: @TaW What is the information value of saving the same string at the beginning of every row? If it is stored in database, then simply having the column named `COMMENT` should be enough, don't you think? Anyway, I posted this as a comment precisely because it does not answer the question, but asks if what it asks is what OP needs, and you're right, it depends on if it matters to the OP or not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SelectionProtected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionprotected(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the current text selection is
>   protected.

For example, you have "Comment:" in the control, the user is able to append the text after it but not remove your text.

So , I make ReadOnly first 7 characters, append a break line and the rest of your control becomes modifiable:

```
RichTextBox.Select(0, "Comment:".Length);
RichTextBox.SelectionProtected = true;
RichTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: This is an interesting property I have missed so far. But it may not be enough: _The protection setting applies until the property is changed to a different value or until the insertion point is moved to a different paragraph within the control._

Comment: @TaW you miss the first part, I think, `If no text is currently selected,`, in the code, I already selected "Comment:"

Comment: Indeed. In fact I had missed the next paragraph. Very cool solution; I just tested and it will let you protect multiple portions of the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
    richTextBox1.ReadOnly = line == 0;
}
```

Not tested very hard; it lets you only edit when the selection/cursor is not on the 1st line..